# SSH Web Tunnel Monitor

Tags: linux, ssh, monitoring, socks

I allow web traffic tunnelling on my linux server over SSH, each user has a account on the server. So how can I monitor their total send and received bandwidth and also monitor requested URL's?

Also i'm running openssh-server and CentoOS

Update:

The reason why i am doing this is for two reasons, one i can fully browse the web encrypted up to the point of my server and i would never do it any other way, as it stops packet capturers from reading through my traffic on public wifi points or on college networks etc...

The second reason is i have a few different VPS in different locations around the world as i'm in the UK and my server is in the US it means i can watch hulu and US only content.

The second point is why i want to monitor bandwidth per user as i let some close people i know use this service to do exactly that. But i have bandwidth limits and a user agreement with my server company.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Why are they using your server to access the web?  Why not require them to setup a port-formward and run through a traditional proxy like squid which logging of visited sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have your reasons for doing this, but taking Zoredache's question as a kind of answer - you could set up squid on your server (if you don't already have it) and have all the web requests run through that.

Surely you are already running some kind of proxy server to allow this anyway - in which case more than likely there is some such functionality available to you through that.  I don't think the fact the traffic is tunneled to the server is of much relevance here, but perhaps you can provide more details on the use case, and how you are currently achieving things.